# Android - Popup dialog on home/native screens

Tags: android, dialog, popup

### edit: The problem was trying to display the dialog and finish() the activity the next line, so there was no view for the dialog to show!  Would be easier if I could just set home-screen as the context for the dialog.

Newbie here.  I know this question has been asked for many times, but there's no full picture on the solution so far.  I first started to run some code without GUI, which is successful by simply setting the theme.  Now, I want to add dialog to display error from the code, but I cannot get it to show!

```
<activity android:name="PopupActivity"
  android:launchMode="singleInstance" android:excludeFromRecents="true"
  android:taskAffinity="" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

So I created an empty view with wrap_content as width and height, but I'm not sure what view element I should use for the AlertDialog object in the activity.  I have tested all my code in another activity with a view, everything works fine, AlertDialog shows without problem.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal">
</LinearLayout>
```

Is there a simple solution?  Or I have to treat the Theme.Dialog view as a normal view and add textview and button to emulate a dialog?

I use AlertDialog.Builder for the dialog creation:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogB = new AlertDialog.Builder(cont);
alertDialogB.setTitle(title);
alertDialogB.setMessage(msg);
...
...
```

IDE: IntelliJ
SDK: 4.1.2

Answer (score 0):

You can create simple dialog with different solutions but I used this for starts with.

Here I am adding list of files with code to clarify your doubts:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.demo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.demo.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.demo.HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**LoginActivity.java**

```
package com.demo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.app.Activity;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    Button login_btn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        login_btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
        login_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_login, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**activity_login.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity" 
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnlogin"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**And one activity which comes as a alert dialog for Login Activity
HomeActivity.java**

```
package com.demo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_home, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**activity_home.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If you want i'll send you another solution which will dynamically creates alert dialog box using list view. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Sanket Thakkar, for your answer and your time.  Actually I have done everything right except I finish() the activity before the dialog can be shown.  And as I expected, no view is needed!  I'm also trying to create generic dialog library for simple dialogs...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I got your question right, but you use an activity for the `AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity);` 
And then just `Dialog dialog = builder.create();
                        dialog.show();`